# Functions of bounded variation and $L^\infty$ functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, bounded-variation

Here are my questions.

- Are $L^\infty$ functions of bounded variation?
- Is the composition of two BV functions still of bounded variation?
- Is $x\mapsto \frac 1{f(x)}$ of bounded variation when $f$ is of bounded variation?

Cheers.

Comment: What do you think about these problems?

Comment: Here are your answers: no, no, no.

Answer (score 5):

As said above: no, no, no. (1) Consider $\sin(1/x)$. (2) Consider $\sqrt{x}$ composed with $x^2\sin^2(1/x)$. (3) Consider $1/x$.